# Turn javascript array of numbers into indexed pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of numbers, like so:

```
[5, 29, 1, 5, 4919, 109, 17]
```

I'd like to turn that into pairs of number based on the index in the array, like this:

```
[[0, 5], [1, 29], [2, 5], [3, 4919], [4, 109], [5, 17]]
```

How can I do that with javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[5, 29, 1, 5, 4919, 109, 17].map(function(x,i){return [i,x];})
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answer suggests using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which is a fine solution and probably what I would use in my own code, but map was introduced in ECMAScript 5, so it might not work in older browsers (without [polyfill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill)).

If you need something more universal, a very simple method would be something like this:

```
var input = [5, 29, 1, 5, 4919, 109, 17];
var output = [];
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    output.push([i, input[i]]);
```

Or this:

```
var input = [5, 29, 1, 5, 4919, 109, 17];
var output = Array(input.length);
for (var i in input)
    output[i] = [i, input[i]];
```

Comment: +1 as this is the only answer not using ES5 features without mentioning it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a library that adds those missing methods for older browsers: http://augmentjs.com/ ~ 5.501 kb